# Why doesn't this "play audio" code work in Chrome but on Safari?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio

I'm desperate, how can I make this code for playing audio file on website work in Chrome. Now it only works in Safari. I'm not interested in solutions where I have to make mp3 files, I want to be able to hear the sound from the google.translate link directly. The audio it should play is "Je m'appelle Sebastién".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>This works from Safari but not chrome</h2>
<audio id="audio" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-&&client=tw-ob&tl=fr&q=je%20m%E2%80%99appelle%20Sebasti%C3%A9n"></audio>

<button id = "button" onclick = "sound ()">Play sound</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function sound (){
let myAudio = document.querySelector('#audio')
myAudio.play()}
</script>

    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). Are there any errors in the console? The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, is it blocked by an extension or the browser? Is the MIME type correct? Look into the **Response** tab inside the Network tab: do you receive what you expect? I’m getting a 404 Not Found response when I try this.

Comment: What's up with `ie=UTF-&&`?

Comment: Shouldn’t `UTF-&` be `UTF-8`? Even if fixed, it’s still a 404, though. It’s probably blocked due to CORS rules.

Comment: it doesn't work because of the CORS policy and it should not. Why this is allowed by Safari I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to use SpeechSynthesis Web API?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Speech Synthesis Web API</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="Je m'appelle Sebastién" />
    <button id="play">Speak!</button>

    <script src="src/speech.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`speech.js`

```js
const elementTextField = document.getElementById("text");
const elementPlayButton = document.getElementById("play");

elementPlayButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const textField = elementTextField.value;
  var toSpeak = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(textField);
  toSpeak.lang = "fr-FR";
  toSpeak.rate = 0.88;
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(toSpeak);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a list of voices I can try? The voice in the example didn't sound very natural. In other voice examples with SpeechSynthesis Web API I found a voice in a roller curtain named "Google français", how do I choose that in the code you posted?

Comment: @sebbe 
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Je m\'appelle Sebastién');
msg.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function(voice) { return voice.name == 'Google français'; })[0];
speechSynthesis.speak(msg);  

// Be aware that 'Google français' is ONLY available on Chrome desktops https://talkrapp.com/speechSynthesis.html

Comment: Merci beaucoup!